# Run application during server boot time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, startup

I have a problem. 
`lsb_release -a` result

No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04 
Release:  17.04 Codename: zesty

and this my auto start script: **start-app**

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          data exchange
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Start data exchange service...
### END INIT INFO
echo 'after reboot' > /home/forte/test.txt
java -cp /home/forte/apps/data-exchange-service-1.0.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher &
exit 0
```

After created I give excute permission

```
chmod +x start-app
```

Then I moved this script under **/etc/init.d** and execute

```
update-rc.d start-app defaults
update-rc.d start-app enable
```

I check the **rc*.d** folder and my scripts link exist under [2,3,4,5]

But when I reboot server it does not run my app.

I also tried **crontab**

```
@reboot /home/forte/apps/start-app
```

But none of them does not work 
Is there any other way?

**extra note**
when I execute

```
/etc/init.d/start-app start
```

my app works normally

Comment: Do you see anything in your /home/forte/test.txt? Do you see any other files in /etc/init.d? I'm not sure but ubuntu 17 is probably using systemd which has a different mechanism for starting system services.

Comment: I checked but was not created after reboot

Answer (score 0):

you could create a systemd unit, is pretty much the same that init.d but since ubuntu uses systemd as init this could be more helpful.

Here is a link to some info about systemd units.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your extra links. I followed it and create systemd units. I enabled service but after reboot service does not start auto. But when I run `systemctl start my.service` it works normally

Comment: maybe `journalctl -xe` can give you some extra info about why does this happen, hope it helps

Comment: I checked but not helped. I tried lots of way. Execute script directly or just execute .sh file but did not work when i reboot the server. Each way i got differen error. For example when i run my java application directly (execstart)  after reboot it gave main class not found but when i run manualy it worls normally. And when i try .sh file after reboot i got chroot error